# 2D: Scaling a character with multiple RigidBody2Ds?

Tags: animation, scale, rigidbody, godot

So, this example is in the Godot Engine, but other engines porbably have this kind of problem, too:

I have a character with multiple `RigidBody2Ds`, that also has a bone skeleton for animation over them. Now, the problem is, that Godot's physics engine handles the transforms of the bodies, so they won't scale properly. If you scale the children (`CollisionShape2Ds` and `Sprites`) the positions will be off. Is anybody aware of a proper way to work around this? Being able to scale these kind of characters would be awesome.

Thanks for all your answers.
Greetings, Footurist

Comment: Scaling physics objects can often be bad for performance and physics stability. Can you tell us more about the game feature this is serving? There might be other ways to achieve your gameplay goals without this particular complication.

Comment: So, I am recreating some games for becoming familiar with the Godot Engine. And right now I have a character, that's being animated, but also is hanging on a joint "in the air". So he has certain bone animations, but also needs to just let his limbs obey the laws of physics. I thought to my self, recreating this kind of character everytime I need him in a different scale seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Could you explain why you need different scales? Are you planning on having a the character change it's distance from the camera? Different zoom levels? What are you trying to achieve with this? @DMGregory already explained that scaling objects usually causes issues.